# How can i make my application to honor post request

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, http-post, forms

we have application which can be launched in browser with URl and also, as an clickable link from another standalone application(our application will be launched within that standalone app). application is launching fine when we enter url in browser but when we use clickable link in standalone application it is not working and throwing following error "**error 405 method not allowed**". after investigation, we figured it is happening because that standalone application is trying to launch our app as POST request whereas the browser initiates it as GET.

How can i make my application to work with POST request??

i tried with following FORM attribute in landing page with method POST but it didn't help.

```
<form name=something method="post" action="www.something.com/virtualdirectory/"
```

*Technology: HTML,AngularJS(urlrootprovider for routing),c# webapi(middle tier)*

Can anyone please guide me to fix this??

Comment: If it works fine entering url directly why would you need a POST at all? Issue really doesn't make sense. Doesn't a regular `<a href>` work?

Comment: @charlietfl the standalone application is controlled by different team and they have like URL's to 100 apps in their container. But to answer your question, they are using POST to send us some data even we dont need that data but due to some limitations on their end they cant call using GET/ href.

Comment: well unfortunately not enough known as to why post is used or why you can't get back end to accept post. Could be a CORS issue if this is cross domain